# How does the block version get set

Tags: mining, source

I noticed that the BLOCK_MAJOR_VERSION is still set to 1 in the cryptonote_config.h. So how is the block version getting updated to 14?

Answer (score 1):

It comes from: [src/hardforks/hardforks.cpp](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/70ceab6c104d5792a7dbbe96efbcc9efcb51c822/src/hardforks/hardforks.cpp)